# Add new input field to ACF Link

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently trying to add an additional input field where users are able to specify an aria-label inside the already existing link field within Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress. I’ve attached an image to give a visual representation of what I am looking to do.

[Link Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrPd.jpg)

Then on the frontend you would use something like $link[aria-label] to get it from the link array.

Any help to achieve this would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to provide an image of ACF? you should already be extremely close.

Answer (score -1):

You can try if that field already exists in the ACF link.

Store that link value in a variable and `print_r` it and check. Check the below code.

```
<?php 
    $link = get_field('YOUR-FIELD-NAME');
    print_r($link);
?>
```